# Python socket programming - Counting attempts does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets

I am trying to program a login system using the library 'socket'. With six failed attempts the server side should do some stuff, but the failed attempts are not counted. Thanks if you can help me.

Client side:

```
    # login logic
    while True:
        # Generate hashed password
        password = input("Password: ")
        hashed_password = hashlib.sha512(password.encode()).hexdigest()
        s.sendall(hashed_password.encode())

        is_password_correct = s.recv(1024)
        if is_password_correct.decode() == "correct_password":
            print(f"{green_sign} You have successfully authorized!")
            break
        elif is_password_correct.decode() == "wrong_password":
            password_trials = s.recv(1024)
            print(f"{yellow_sign} Wrong password! Try again... ({int(password_trials.decode())} / 6)")
```

Server side:

```
        # login logic
        password_trials = 0
        while True:
            # check hashed password
            recv_password = conn.recv(1024)
            if recv_password.decode() == stored_hashed_password:
                password_trials = 0
                print(f"{gray_sign} User has authorized successfully!")
                conn.sendall(b"correct_password")
                break
            elif recv_password.decode() != stored_hashed_password:
                password_trials += 1
                conn.sendall(b"wrong_password")
                conn.sendall(str(password_tries).encode())

            if password_trials == 6:
                """ Do some stuff """
```

Comment: Are you using TCP or UDP? TCP is a stream protocol, it doesn't maintain message boundaries. So the client might receive both `wrong_password` and the number of tries as a single message, not separate messages. As a result, your comparison in the client will fail, even though the trial was counted.

Comment: I use **TCP**. Would it be better if I use UDP? Actually UDP is used for streaming like Netflix and with TCP the order and the actual arrival of the packets. Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's true, UDP could reorder the packets, which would cause other problems.

Comment: So you can not help me?

Comment: You need to design a protocol that allows you to determine message boundaries.

Comment: And how would I program this? I have absolutely no idea how to do this. I also searched on google but found nothing right :(

Comment: This is more involved than I can answer here. Take a look at how common protocols like SMTP and HTTP work.

Comment: I will do that. Thanks for your answers and your help :)